# Domain adaptation on Keras

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am developing an image classifier using CNN on Keras. Since the images were taken from multiple domains, I would like to try domain adaptation.

To simultaneously train an image classifier as well as make domain-invariant features, I posed a negative loss weight for domain loss like this in Keras.

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
          loss={'main_output': 'categorical_crossentropy', 'domain_output': 'categorical_crossentropy'},
          loss_weights={'main_output': 1, 'domain_output': -0.1},
          metrics={'main_output': 'accuracy, 'domain_output': 'accuracy'})
```

Here, `main output` is the softmax output for image classification, and `domain_output` is the softmax output for domain classification (target: domain label).

- Is this implementation correct for domain adaption?
- Is this approach functionally same as the "gradient reversal layer" (reversing the gradient for domain classification) proposed in  [this paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/ganin15.pdf)?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the full code for implementation of DA? I'm really confused in this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well - answer for both of your question is yes (as long as you have separate model branches and outputs for the domain and class prediction).

1. This implementation is correct - as domain adaptation need reversal gradients (which is equivalent to have a loss with negative weight),
2. As stated above - yes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer should be:
1. Yes, it is one kind of domain adaption.
2. No, it is not the implementation of that paper.

It is because of that for "gradient reversal layer", the gradient reversal happens before several fully-connected layers. It means these layers are trained for discriminating domains. If you directly just reverse the loss as you did in your code, it will make the last layers divergent, too. Basically, you are training nothing.

I am not sure the final results though, but I guess it could be worse than the original implementation of "gradient reversal layer".